# How to plot 1/x^x in Blender using Z function surface

Tags: add-on, mathematics

I am looking to plot math functions in Blender using the Z function surface Add-On.

It works great for functions such as:

```
1/x**2
```

But fails for functions like:

```
1/x**X
```

which gives **error**:

```
Error evaluating expression: 1/( x**x ) (Check the console for more info)
```

The console shows:

```
TypeError: can't convert complex to float
```

...despite Google and Wolfram Alpha being able to plot these easily:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap your expression in parens add a [`.real` or `.imag`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/numbers.html#numbers.Complex.real) to get the real or imaginary part, e.g. `(1/(x**x)).real`.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you.